# What is the efficiency of lambdas wrapped inside lambdas?

Tags: c++, c++11

Say i'm recursing through directories and I have a bunch of filters

1. If the file matches this string
2. If the directory matches that string
3. Exclude these file extensions
4. Exclude if you ever hit directory X
5. etc

There's multiple options to check here per file and functionally using them as a filter. I can turn each option that's turned on into a lambda, and then apply a list of lambdas to see if I include or exclude a certain file. I could also wrap the lambdas into each other ending up with one lambda that will return true or false. I've come across this pattern possibility several times and I don't know what's the correct answer. For convenience I usually choose making a list of lambdas.

Comment: The "correct answer" is whatever works. Odds are good that your application speed will not be governed by its performance when filtering files. Hell, odds are good that *getting* the directory list will take longer than filtering it.

Comment: The idea you have proposed seems flexible and extensible. These are both good things. Do you have any reason to believe that this code will be a performance hit? Have you profiled your code? Are you planning to use it on hundreds of thousands, or millions of files? Remember, early optimization is a bad habit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should be just as efficient as handwritten function objects doing the same work, but with less typing.  Compilers don't need anything very magical to implement lambdas, they can just implement a uniquely-named class with an `operator()` defined, and declare data members for any captured variables.